# Chrome Browser draggable Bug disables dragging in single-page app with Map

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a single-page app built in jQuery which has some custom controls sitting on top of a customized [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com) map. A bug manifests where an **li** element with `draggable="true"` won't drag. However, if I click on the map once, and then try dragging the **li** element it works.

In order to reproduce the bug I have to execute a very specific sequence of steps during which I never click on the map itself. This sequence of steps is something that a typical user might actually try to do. Furthermore, if I do `$('#map').click()` to simulate the click it does not solve the problem. That is, an actual click is necessary.

I've tested in Chrome and Firefox and it only happens in Chrome.

I can't find any information about this bug on the web, has anyone ever heard of this before? And if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A **workaround**....
Well I finally tried the following:

```
    $('#_GMapContainer').click();
```

... and it seems to be working. This is an element that is created by *leafletjs* automatically.

Before, I had actually been issuing the click on `#_GMapContainer`'s parent element.

Comment: I recently discovered a "bug" in my single page app that manifested in  a very similar way.  Turns out that I had an input field with `type="password"` that maintained focus after login even though its parent layer had `display:none;`. As a result drag events were not registering prior to a click somewhere on the page which would cause the input to lose focus. May be related, may not, but it took me a long time to hunt it down and this might help someone.